# Check if nxm block of 1s is inside binary matrix (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, search, matrix, find, pattern-matching

I have a 90x89 binary matrix (I can't attach .mat files so I can't provide the matrix). In short, the 1s are good and 0s are bad. I want a quick way to check and return any nxm blocks of all 1s within the large matrix. For example, I want to find out if there are any 3x6 (n=3, m=6) blocks of all 1s within the binary matrix. If there are, return the row and col for each cell within each block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find your result, it helps to think of the matrix as an image.

An erosion is an image processing operation that returns the minimum value within a local neighborhood: for each pixel (matrix element) you look at all the values in a neighborhood (in your case this would be a 3x6 rectangle) an find the minimum. This is the value that you write to that pixel in the output image.

Now, if a matrix element is in the middle of a 3x6 block with all 1s, then the minimum is 1. If there is even a single 0 in there, the minimum will be 0. So, the output image will have 1s in the middle element of each 3x6 block of 1s.

If you have access to the Image Processing Toolbox, use [the `imerode` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html).

If you want to find the coordinates of all matrix elements within these blocks, you can convert the output of the erosion using a dilation. This is the inverse operation, and will set to 1 all the elements belonging to these 3x6 blocks.

For example:

```
% Create some test matrix (66% are 1s, so we have some chance of finding a 3x6 block):
a = randi([0,2], 100,100) > 0;

% Look for 3x6 blocks:
b = imerode(a, ones(3,6));
any(b(:))              % returns true, hopefully
nnz(b)                 % returned 2 for me, there's 2 of these blocks

% Find all pixels belong the these two blocks:
c = imdilate(b, ones(3,6));
nnz(c)                 % returned 2*18 for me, as expected
[row,col] = find(c);   % Now [row(i),col(i)] are the indices to one of these pixels
```

Comment: Thanks you! I was not aware about erosions. Very interesting learning about them. This worked well